# How to draw OpenGL ES context above the camera's video in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenGL Layer on top of Video on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204664/opengl-layer-on-top-of-video-on-iphone)

I want to draw some OpenGL ES context above the camera's video in iOS 4.

I am using this tutorial from Apple to get the video frames from the camera:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1702.html

Works like a charm. I am able to get video frames from the camera, and display them.

But - I want to display some OpenGL ES drawing above the video. That context should have a transparent background, and display only what I draw.

The code used to display the video:

```
 AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session1];
```

UIView *aView = [self view];
 previewLayer.frame = aView.bounds; // Assume you want the preview layer to fill the view.
 [aView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];

The code used to display the OpenGL drawing:

```
  glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);
```

[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];

Problem is - I can only draw a full OpenGL layer (meaning, with a background, say black) and cannot only draw some artifacts of opengl, with a transparent background (so that the user can see the video below the opengl context).

Thanks alot,
fiod

Answer (score 1):

Render a plane textured with the camera images behind your 3d model